# Wrap withRouter in an ES7 function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a DetailProducts function, how can I wrap DetailProducts in withRouter. Thanks

```
import React from "react";
import details from "../../CSS/ProductsCss/details.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export default function DetailProducts() {
  return (
    <div className="single-product">
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try `withRouter(DetailProducts)`?

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly happens when you try @slideshowp2 's suggestion?

Comment: The only problem that may happen is forgoing the provider layer I mentioned that in my answer,  what else do you think can cause a problem, @AbirTaheer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the react-router-dom's `Provider` on the ancestor of this component

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

// for example I put it in the really beginning of the app
// you may change the placement of <Router />
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Then wrap you component inside `withRouter` HOC

```
import React from "react";
import details from "../../CSS/ProductsCss/details.css";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function DetailProducts(props) {
  // you have access to following and even more things
  const { match, location, history } = props;

  return (
    <div className="single-product">
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(DetailProducts)
```

### Migration:

as version 5 suggest you should update your component to use the hook version instead.

> Replace all uses of withRouter with hooks. [Upgrade to v5.1](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/174fb105eef4bb44485d8d2ad4f2bfaa082fa750/docs/upgrading/v5.md#upgrade-to-react-router-v51)
>
> Replace any withRouter usage with hooks. They give you access to all the same stuff. Again, although withRouter is not deprecated in 5.1, it's a weird API when you can compose your state with hooks instead. It will also most likely be deprecated in a future release. [post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/)

Here is a list of available hooks which are pretty clear by their name,  but if you want to dig into them. check the [Hook api](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) section in the doc

- useHistory
- useLocation
- useParams
- useRouteMatch

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are the preferred method now. It might look something like this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function DetailProducts() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/some-path");
  }

  return (
    <div className="single-product">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click this</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) for the other useful hooks which provide coverage of the other functionality from `withRouter`.